# Creating multiple variables based on an integer

Tags: python, variables

I want to create multiple variables based on a number that I have defined.
Currently, I have a client and a server running and every time a client joins, I want the server to create a variable.  Each user is assigned a number:

```
list_of_addr = []
user_num = 0
recv_verf, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(2048)
if(recv_verf == 'connect'):
    recv_user, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(2048)
    list_of_addr.append('User:' + recv_user + ' # ' + str(user_num) + '\n')
    user_num = user_num + 1
    print 'User:' + recv_user + ' # ' + str(user_num) + ' connected'
```

I want a variable to be created here based on this number. Similar to user_(user_num) = 0.
I don't know how else to explain this. Sorry is this is vague.

Comment: Why you don't use a `list`, or a `dict`?

Comment: You could make a class to house any variables about a client, and on each 'connect' append a new class item into the list. Now you can store more information, and have it in a way that is neat and easily acceptable. (*you can do everything from within the lists, but as requirements grow your list could become very messy and hard to handle* but it's your call)

Comment: Do you not have anything to cater for `sessions` or `authorisation`?

Answer (score 9):

Don't do this. If you want to have a dynamic group of items pointed to by names, that's what a `dict` is for. If you just want an list of items in a particular order, that's what a `list` is for.

Variable names should be kept to what you, the programmer, actually write in your code. Down the other path lies madness.

Answer (score 0):

A dict would be an appropriate solution for this :

```
list_of_addr = []
user_num = 0
recv_verf, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(2048)
if(recv_verf == 'connect'):
    recv_user, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(2048)
    list_of_addr.append(dict(user=recv_user, number=user_num))
    user_num = user_num + 1
    print 'User: {0} # {1} connected'.format(list_of_addr[-1]['user'], list_of_addr[-1]['number']
```